# Linq to sql com subquery

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Tenho duas tabelas, e gostaria de obter apenas os dados da tabela A, filtrando pela tabela relacionada B. Gostaria de saber como escrever essa consulta com Linq to Sql em C#. Eu escrevi o exemplo abaixo no Sql Server para ficar mais fácil o entendimento.

```
    Declare @tabela_a as table (
        ID_A int, --PK
        nome varchar(20)
    )
    Declare @tabela_b as table (
        ID_B int, -- PK
        ID_A int, -- FK
        nome varchar(20)
    )
    insert into @tabela_a values (1, 'AAA')
    insert into @tabela_a values (2, 'BBB')
    insert into @tabela_a values (3, 'CCC')

    insert into @tabela_b values (1, 1, 'A1')
    insert into @tabela_b values (2, 1, 'A2')
    insert into @tabela_b values (3, 1, 'A3')
    insert into @tabela_b values (4, 2, 'B1')
    insert into @tabela_b values (5, 2, 'B2')
    insert into @tabela_b values (6, 2, 'B3')

-- Exemplo de Query que eu gostaria que seja executada
    SELECT * FROM @TABELA_A A
    WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT NULL FROM @TABELA_B B 
        WHERE ID_A = A.ID_A 
        AND B.NOME IN ('A1', 'A2', 'B3')
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tabelaA.Where(t1 => tabelaB.Any(t2 => t2.id.equals(t1.id) && (t2.nome.equals("A1") || t2.nome.equals("A2") || t2.nome.equals("B3"))).ToList()
```

Comment: @Rafael Marcos Respondi a sua questão? Se sim, marque a minha resposta como resolvida.